# SQL Insert/Update does fails, does not invoke errors

Tags: mysql, perl, dbi

Afternoon everyone,

I'm currently trying to insert or update form field values via params into a mysql after some simple validation. The form submits, but does not actually execute any of the operations and does not raise a syntax or database connection error. I know my connection string works because I fetched values from it to compare to in the code prior to the nested evaluation blocks shown below. The foreach loops were inserted as an alternate means of validating that the values have indeed been altered in the table. Your help is greatly appreciated, as always:

```
my $dbusr = param("dbuser");
    my $dbpw = param("dbpass");
    my $dbmail = param("dbemail");
    my $dbtel = param("dbphone");
    my $postflag = param("Submit");

    if ($dbusr ne "") {
        $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE username LIKE ?");
        $sth->execute('$dbusr');
        warn( $DBI::errstr ) if ( $DBI::err );

        my @results = $sth->fetchall_arrayref();

        foreach(@results){
            if ($dbusr eq $_){
                $loopval = 1;
            }
        }

        unless($loopval){
            $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO USER
                       (username, password, phone, email)
                        values
                       (?,?,?,?)");
            $sth->execute($dbusr, $dbpw, $dbtel, $dbmail);
            warn( $DBI::errstr ) if ( $DBI::err );

            $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE username LIKE ?");
            $sth->execute('$dbusr');

            @results = $sth->fetchall_arrayref();

            foreach(@results){
                if ($dbusr eq $_){
                    $successflag = 1;
                }
            }
        }
        else{
            $sth = $dbh->prepare("UPDATE USER
                        SET (password = ?, phone = ?, email = ?)
                        WHERE username = ?");
            $sth->execute($dbpw, $dbtel, $dbmail, $dbusr);
            warn( $DBI::errstr ) if ( $DBI::err );

            $sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM USER WHERE username LIKE ?");
            $sth->execute('$dbusr');

            @results = $sth->fetchall_arrayref();

            foreach(@results){
                if ($dbusr eq $_){
                    $successflag = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tried RaiseError? `$dbh = DBI->connect($dsn, $user, $password, {RaiseError => 1});`

Comment: I did, nothing comes up unfortunately, even when using the perl command to run it from the terminal...

Comment: @learnenburn `RaiseError` will 1) check things that you aren't currently checking (like your `prepare`s and some of the `execute`s) 2) save you from having to pepper your code with `or die ...` or similar. In this case, you have a logic error as Marc B pointed out, so `RaiseError` won't find anything, but it will make your code safer and more readable.

Answer (score 2):

Basic Perl: `'`-quoted strings do NOT interpolate variables:

```
    $sth->execute('$dbusr');
                  ^--    ^---
```

You're literally passing `$`, `d`, `b`, etc... to your query as the placeholder value.

Try

```
     $sth->execute($dbusr); // note the lack of ' quotes
```

instead.

Comment: That's a great catch, I appreciate it. The variables inserted into the statement handle for the insert/update statements are not quoted though.

Comment: Yes, but they all depend on the very FIRST query executing and returning something. Since that one's being executed with your incorrect `'$dbusr'` parameter, you never get anything useful back and everything else is simply skipped.

Comment: Still unable to run it correctly after fixing the quotes... Is there possibly a problem in the conditions of the logic structure?

Comment: @learnenburn ever tried debugging? It could be as simple as `warn "here I am"`

Answer (score 0):

You are searching for entire `rows` with the `SELECT * FROM USER WHERE username LIKE ?` statement, and are then fetching all the rows in one go with

```
my @results = $sth->fetchall_arrayref();
```

That method ["returns a reference to an array that contains one reference per row."](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchall_arrayref), but you are treating the returned value as an list of usernames:

```
foreach(@results){
    if ($dbusr eq $_){
        $loopval = 1;
    }
}
```

To make this work you should just fetch the `username` column, and treat the returned rows as references of references. And as you look for exact matches in the database replace `LIKE` with `=`:

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare("SELECT username FROM USER WHERE username = ?");
$sth->execute($dbusr); # no quoting
die( $DBI::errstr ) if ( $DBI::err ); # what else to do if the execute fails?

my $results = $sth->fetchall_arrayref();  # an arrayref is returned

foreach(@$results){  # de-reference the array
    if ($dbusr eq $_->[0]){  # each row is an arrayref, look in first element
        $loopval = 1;
    }
}
```

(Of course the same applies to the second search.)